# Fancybox gallery from another fancybox - display issue

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am setting up a gallery and I'm having a little problem that I absolutly don't know how to solve.
Here is how I've built my project:

- clicking on a thumbnail launches a standard inline fancybox with some information
- inside each inline fancybox, I have a manual trigger to a fancybox image gallery, like this:

```html
<a id="galerie'.$projet->id.'" href="#" onclick="$(\'a#proj'.$projet->id.'\').eq(0).trigger(\'click\'); return false;"><img src="img/ico_img.png" alt="images"> Galerie d\'images</a>
```

Everything works fine (as you can check on my [development website](http://www.1tuitif.com/lanton/)), except for 2 projects which are the only ones to have only **1 image** in their gallery: their image is displayed at the top of my viewport and are much smaller than the others (see "Quartiers nords de Valenton" and "Complexe sportif de l'aviation").
I don't have any clue on what is happening with those projects and why my fancybox gallery is broken if I display one single image...

Here is my code:

```php
echo '
<div class="centreur">
<div class="wrapper">
<span class="thumb"><a href="#info'.$projet->id.'" class="fancybox-info" title=""><img class="thumbnail" src="img/projets/'.$image0['id'].'-'.$image0['projet'].'.jpg" alt="'.$projet->titre.'"/></a></span>
<div class="caption">'.$projet->titre.'</div>
</div>
<div class="hidden">
<div id="info'.$projet->id.'" style="min-width:400px;max-width:400px;" class="descrframe">
<h2>'.$projet->titre.'</h2>'.$prix.'
<div>
<center><img class="firstslide" src="img/projets/'.$image0['id'].'-'.$image0['projet'].'.jpg" alt="'.$projet->titre.'"/></center>
</div>
<div class="linkstyle"><a id="galerie'.$projet->id.'" href="#" onclick="$(\'a#proj'.$projet->id.'\').eq(0).trigger(\'click\'); return false;"><img src="img/ico_img.png" alt="images"> Galerie d\'images</a></div>
<table class="transtable"><tbody>
'.$ville.$pays.$maitrise.$equipe.$mandataire.$cout.$superficie.$date.'
</tbody></table>
</div>';
$i = 0;
foreach($images as $image){
$galid = $i == 0 ? 'id="proj'.$projet->id.'"' : '';
echo '<a href="img/projets/'.$image->id.'-'.$image->projet.'.jpg" class="fancybox-thumb" rel="proj'.$projet->id.'" title="'.$image->credit.'" '.$galid.'></a>';
$i++;
}
echo '</div></div>';
}
```

And here are my fancybox configurations:

```js
$(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox({
    prevEffect  : 'elastic',
    nextEffect  : 'elastic',
    openEffect  : 'fade',
    closeEffect : 'fade',
    margin      : [120,50,500,50],
    padding     : [0,0,0,0],
    loop        : false,
    maxWidth    : 900,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    topRatio    : 0.5,
    openOpacity : true,
    closeOpacity: true,
    beforeShow: function(){
        $.fancybox.wrap.bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
                return false;
        });
        }
    helpers : {
        title : {
            type : 'outside'
        },
        overlay : {
            opacity : 0.9,
            css : {
                'background-image' : 'url(img/pattern.png)',
                'background-color' : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)'
            }
        },
        thumbs  : {
            width   : 50,
            height  : 50,
            position: 'bottom'
        }
    }
});

$(".fancybox-info").fancybox({
    prevEffect  : 'elastic',
    nextEffect  : 'elastic',        
    openEffect  : 'fade',
    closeEffect : 'fade',
    margin      : [120,50,50,50],
    padding     : [0,0,0,0],
    loop        : false,
    maxWidth    : 900,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    topRatio    : 0.5,
    openOpacity : true,
    closeOpacity: true,
    beforeShow: function(){
        $.fancybox.wrap.bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
                return false;
        });
        },
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            opacity : 0.9,
            css : {
                'background-image' : 'url(img/pattern.png)',
                'background-color' : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I use fancybox v2.1.3 with jquery v1.7.2 if that matters.

Any help would be highly appreciated, as I don't know where to look to solve this strange behavior!
Thanks in advance!
kpuche

PS: I'm french so forgive my poor english :)

Comment: I tried downgrading to 2.0.6... And it works! I just have a little issue with the overlay which doesn't appear anymore, but I think I can fix that easily.
That's very strange...

Comment: remove the `contextmenu` so we can use firebug easier

Comment: Well, I cannot see the problem since you rolled-back to v2.0.6 with a css file for v2.1.3

Comment: I updated all my fancybox-related files to 2.1.3 and now the "small size" issue appears on all my images. I also updated jquery to 1.8.2 to make sure it matches your own demo configuration. I'm a bit lost...

Comment: I think I found what appears to be my own mistake! Margin was set to [120,50,**500**,50] instead of [120,50,50,50]... I'm sorry, all seems to work fine now. Thanks for keeping on improving this great plugin :)